# Occasional gRPC unknown errors when running inside docker container

Tags: docker, grpc, grpc-python

I am trying to connect with a gRPC server running inside a docker. However, I get the below errors sometimes:

```
File "xxx/grpc/_channel.py", line 826, in __call__
    return _end_unary_response_blocking(state, call, False, None)
  File "xxx/grpc/_channel.py", line 729, in _end_unary_response_blocking
    raise _InactiveRpcError(state)
grpc._channel._InactiveRpcError: <_InactiveRpcError of RPC that terminated with:
    status = StatusCode.UNKNOWN
        details = "Error in service handler!"
debug_error_string = "{"created":"@1599177910.752607903","description":"Error received from peer ipv6:[::1]:50096","file":"src/core/lib/surface/call.cc","file_line":1062,"grpc_message":"Error in service handler!","grpc_status":2}"
```

Interestingly, it is an inconsistent failure and doesn't happen every time. I am able to connect with the server in the container successfully a few times. This failure is random and happen roughly once in every 5 times. Can anyone provide some pointers on this failure? Thanks.